# .rawQuery order by doesn't work

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-order-by

Before I added in "order by", my statement works well and data is able to be displayed. After I added "order by", it is unable to work! Is there some thing wrong with my statement?

```
        Cursor c = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT companyNameEng FROM " +
                TABLE_NAME + "ORDER BY companyNameEng asc", null);

        if (c != null ) {
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
              womenName.add(c.getString(0)); // Get the current subj
                                                      // code, add to list
          }
          sampleDB.close();
        }
      sampleDB.close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knowing exactly how it fails would help us answer the question, but a guess is that you are missing a space character before the "ORDER BY" part of your statement. Unless `TABLE_NAME` includes a trailing space, this will make for an invalid SQL statement.